# How can column names by used in a complex dplyr function that uses base R elements?

Tags: r, dplyr

First, this question is likely a repeat, however the solutions I've tried (eg using `enquo()` and `!!`, or `get()`, or `{{}}`) have not yielded results.

**The Problem**

I have a function that needs to take column names passed to it in a pipeline, perform a series of dplyr-based functions with some base R components, and return the new dataframe. The problem is that the function will not take the column names passed to it as variables in the referenced dataframe, treating them as strings instead.

**The Data**

This code will create a usable dataframe for this problem:

```
df_ext <- tibble(ID = c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5)),
                 TIME = rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 2),
                 VAL = c(0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 5, 0, 1, 4))
```

**The Current Function**

Here's a version of the function that I can share. It's designed to create a series of categories for the data I pass to it, but this is a simplified version that just calculates some basic groupings (ie, it doesn't do much of anything).

```
my_fun <- function(.data, id, time, val){
  
  require("dplyr")
  
  df <- df |>
    group_by(id) |>
    mutate(val_lag = if_else(val > 0, time - lag(time, default = 0), 0)) |>
    mutate(first_time = min(time),
           last_time = max(time),
           first_val_pos = ifelse(any(val), min(time[val > 0]), NA),
           last_val_pos = ifelse(any(val > 0), max(time[val > 0]), NA)) |>
    group_by(grp = cumsum(val_lag == 0)) |>
    mutate(val_pos_run = cumsum(val_lag)) |>
    ungroup() |>
    group_by(id) |>
    mutate(ada_bl = ifelse(first_val_pos <= 0, val[time == first_val_pos], 0)) |>
    ungroup()
  
  df
  
  
}

df_ext |>
  my_fun(id = ID, time = TIME, val = VAL)
```

If anyone can get the columns from the dataframe to pass into the function and get treated as columns in the pipe-referenced dataframe, you'd be ending a very frustrating headache.

Comment: start by doing `df %>% group_by({{id}})` change everything after that

Comment: @onyambu Change everything meaning put all the column variables in ```{{}}```?

Comment: Yes. Anytime you use one of the function parameters (`id`, `time`, or `val`), they should be inside `{{ }}`. I'm not sure what you were expcting with `val_lag`. Were you trying to do partial name substitution?

Comment: yes. any variable on the RHS of `=`. do not put variables like `val_lag` in `{{}}` just the 3 passed variables

Comment: anything on the LHS of `=` can be changed using `'{{val}}_lag' :=` Note I am using `:=` operator. Check [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#one-or-more-user-supplied-expressions)

Comment: @onyambu That didn't seem to work. Now I get the error ``` Error in UseMethod("group_by") : no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "NULL" ```

Comment: @MrFlick val_lag basically creates a lagging column of times wherever val is > 0. I ultimately need to add up times between two val measurements but reset the addition whenever val drops below 0. It's a little messy; any feedback is welcome.